# Why does terminal become unresponsive after I use certain git commands?

Tags: git, terminal

Very often (every time really) after I use the command `git log` my terminal becomes unresponsive to further input, this is on OSX. Is there a command that I don't know about that will make the terminal active again instead of just quitting the terminal and starting over?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are inside a program that displays the log without scrolling, most likely `less`, which can be exited by pressing the `q` key.

Comment: @lampShade: and if that is the case, `d` will scroll down and `b` will scroll up.

Answer (score 1):

Just press <kbd>q</kbd> to quit from `less`.