# Revert to original version of a file in git (before even adding)

Tags: git, clearcase

I am new in `Git` and my experience is from `Clearcase`.
In `Clearcase` when I wanted to modify a file, I `checked-out` the file to make it writable, modified it and if I was not happy with the changes I simply did an `undo checkout` going back to the original version of the file.
With `git` it is like black box.
I can start writing to my file (it is not read only, right?) and then I am supposed to do `add` followed by `commit`.
But what if I am not happy with my changes and decided not to even `add`?
How do I go back to the original file removing my modifications essentially?

Comment: `git checkout HEAD -- path/to/file`

Answer (score 4):

The `git status` output tells you how to do so:

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
```

Use `git checkout -- <file>` to discard changes even before `add`.

If you have already `add` the file and then you find it's not satisfactory,

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
```

Use `git reset HEAD <file>` to unstage.

Comment: `git status` reports on the whole code base or the current directory? Confused on this. I tried to run it in a large code base and seemed to take forever and I killed it

Comment: @Cratylus You may add files/folders (e.g. data files, binary files, etc) to a `.gitignore` file to stop tracking them. Typically a code base should not contain too many changed files.

Comment: @Cratylus What are the files `git` is reporting?

Comment: Yang:I stopped `git status` after waiting for ~20secs. I assumed that it scanned all the repository to see the status. May be I am thinking this in the `Clearcase` model I have in my mind and I shouldn't

Comment: @Cratylus  Can you use `git status | more` to see page by page what files it's reporting?

Comment: Thank you!I will try this as soon as I can. +1

Comment: if `git status` takes >20 secs, `git status|more` will not be any better. you seem to have quite an unoptimized repo there.

Answer (score 2):

> May be I am thinking this in the Clearcase model I have in my mind and I shouldn't

Yes: see the [main differences between ClearCase and Git here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645771/6309).

Check "[Git Status Takes a Long Time to Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183769/git-status-takes-a-long-time-to-complete)" to see why git status takes a long time: it shouldn't exceed a few seconds at most (unless there is a [pager issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6005054/6309)).

Remember your git repo is much smaller than a ClearCase Vob. I have Vobs which are huge (several Terabytes). A git repo shouldn't exceed a few Megabytes, in order to be cloned around efficiently.
Make sure your current repo doesn't represent what was a huge ClearCase Vob, with potentially multiple projects in it.

Regarding your initial question, I like the `unadd/unstage`alias defined in "[Undo '`git add`' before commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3688108/6309)".

```
git config --global alias.unadd 'reset HEAD --'
git config --global alias.unstage 'reset HEAD --'
```